# Unexplained outage due to faulty (?) Readiness check results

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-health-check, kubernetes-pod

**TL;DR**:
At an unexpected point in time, all the "web"-pods handling traffic coming from our ingress became unhealthy. About an hour or so, and then everything was healthy again. I'm trying to figure out what happened, as it does not seem like any of my actions caused the sudden repair. I had about an hour of downtime and I don't know why, which is scary (luckily it is not production...yet).

---

I'll describe the situation as best as I can; At a moment no significant changes were happening to the platform/sources the external uptime check for our kubernetes cluster (GKE) alerted me that the platform was unreachable. Sure enough. When performing a request to the endpoint, I got an `HTTP Error 502`.

When describing one of the web-pods, I noticed the health-check was failing:

```
  Warning  Unhealthy              11m (x3 over 11m)  kubelet, gke-test-001-web-6a31v8hq-p5ff  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.52.25.179:3000/healthz/full: dial tcp 10.52.25.179:3000: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Investigating further, it was clear that all `Readiness` probes on all web-pods were failing; This was causing the outage.

> Another weird thing to note is the following: Currently for these
>   web-pods the `Readiness` and `Liveness` probes are exactly the same.
>   While the `Readiness` checks were consistently marked as `Failed`, the
>   `Liveness` probes never did.

I decided to investigate the issue further and I noticed that the endpoints set for the `Readiness` checks worked perfectly fine from the following locations:

**From the POD:**

```
root@webpod-76c8ctc6t8-2prjz:/var/lib/webapp# curl -iL 10.52.25.179:3000/healthz/full.json
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"healthy":true,"message":"success"}
```

**From the NODE:**

```
root@gke-test-001-web-6a31v8hq-p5ff ~ $ curl -iL http://10.52.25.179:3000/healthz/full.json
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"healthy":true,"message":"success"}
```

This is while the health checks keep coming back as `Failed`. Somehow I'm getting different results than what the kubelet on each of these nodes is getting?

What I did notice is the following:

```
[Mon Oct 29 16:06:57 2018] cbr0: port 16(veth34a6a4ce) entered disabled state
```

That looks to me like the pod-overlay-network's network bridge got disabled, but if that was really causing an issue I wouldn't be able to reach the pod's IP at all...

I tried the following things:

- Validate the deemed "unhealthy" pods (they were healthy according to me)
- `ifup` and `ifdown` the `cbr0` interface
- Kill the kubelet on one of the nodes and check if that fixed the respective `Readyness` checks (it didn't)
- Reboot a node and check if that fixed the respective `Readyness` checks (it didn't)
- Delete all nodes in the node pool assigned to the web-pods and see if fresh ones fixed the issue (it didn't)

And as suddenly as it came, before I was able to determine the issue, after about exactly an hour, my pods became healthy again and the platform was functioning fine...

Anyone who knows what happened here? Any tips on what I can do if this occurs again?

(Please note that the time in the snippets might differ greatly, as these have been taken from different points in time; Timestamps are UTC)

Comment: Are you using `PreEmptible` nodes by chance?

Comment: We are avoiding the use of `PreEmptible` nodes, they are disabled for all our node pools.

Comment: Based on everything you did, you ruled out most possibilities, this to me, seems like an issue with the kubelet running the readiness probe. I'm not really sure if that can be checked with GKE, you might want to reach out to Google so they can check the master logs

Comment: I'm afraid that is the only option I have left at this point, exactly. Thanks for taking the time to read my question (everyone).

Answer (score 0):

This issue was eventually unrelated to failed readiness checks.

The actual cause was a configmap that did not get loaded in the correct location due to human error!